# MailChimp template variables

Tags: c#, mailchimp

So far my site has been using html files on my server. Now I want to utilize Mailchimp and it's template.

This is my html file where I dynamically replace the variables using String's replace in C#.

```
 <h1>
        <img src="http://john.doe/test.png" border="0" /></h1>
    <hr />
    <div style="padding-left: 30px;">
        <p>
            You have joined John Doe, where you can sell art direct to the public.</p>
        <h2>Username and password</h2>
        <p>
            Here's a reminder of your username and password.</p>
        <p>
            Username:
            <% Email %>
            <br />Password: 
            <% Password %>
        </p>
        <p>
            To log in simply go to
            <a href="">John Doe</a></p>
        <h2>Thanks for joining!</h2>
    </div>
```

So `<% Email %>` and `<% Password %>` are dynamically populated. How could I achieve the same in MailChimp template? I visited this page http://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/template-language/ but it is not clear how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want merge tags

For example: instead of <% email %> use *|EMAIL|*

http://kb.mailchimp.com/merge-tags/all-the-merge-tags-cheat-sheet for a list of available merge tags. If you want to send out the password, you probably don't want to use mailchimp at all; you probably want to use [Mandrill](https://www.mandrill.com/) (from the same company). Also consider SendGrid; or just google 'email api'

Comment: Agree, but I'll go a step farther: if you can produce someone's password to send back to them, you're doing something very, very wrong. [You should never store a cleartext password](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/why-passwords-should-be-hashed/).